# how to print dataframe to console?

Tags: python, pyqt5, spyder

I am using pyqt5 and spyder. I am debugging my code so I'd like to print some dataframe result into spyder console. Without using GUI, I can just use print(df.head()). Now with GUI, I don't know how? even with print(), I don't see any printing result in spyder console. I googled ir for a long time and I still cannot find a solution.

Comment: Can u convert it to a json string?

Comment: @Ctznkane525 We can use [`pandas.DataFrame.to_string`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_string.html) to convert the dataframe to a string, but it's not a JSON string.

Comment: Thanks, once using to_string, how do i print it out to spyder console?

Comment: also how do you guys debug code with GUI? Thanks